# Master branch missing files after merge, files were reported in git merge output

Tags: git

I have a branch called test-branch (I know the name should be just test), and I did a `git merge test-branch` from inside master. The merge was successful, but files are missing from the master branch. However, these files were reported in the `git merge` output. For example, this was reported:

.../cybertrust/tms/controller/TrustController.java | 556 +++++++++++++++++++

But this file isn't present in master. If I run git merge again it says already up to date.

**Edit**

None of the changes were merged. Not even for existing files.
The output in git bash:

```
Findorgri@DESKTOP-7TIPI9E MINGW64 ~/git/trust-management (master)
$ git merge test-branch
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 TMS-listener-module/A13-certificate.pem            |  34 ++
 TMS-listener-module/A17-certificate.txt            |  32 ++
 TMS-listener-module/application.properties         |  47 ++
 TMS-listener-module/log4j.xml                      |  16 +
...
 98 files changed, 7998 insertions(+), 818 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 TMS-listener-module/A13-certificate.pem
 create mode 100644 TMS-listener-module/A17-certificate.txt
 create mode 100644 TMS-listener-module/log4j.xml
 create mode 100644 TMS-listener-module/logback.xml
 create mode 100644 TMS-listener-module/src/main/java/com/cybertrust/authentication/AuthClient.java
```

**Edit 2:**

I did `git reset --hard HEAD` in order to undo the merge. And then I did `git push`. Now master seems truly up to date. Couple of questions:

1. The two branches have the same SHA now. Is it certain now that master has everything? Should I check something else to make sure?
2. Can someone explain what happened exactly? I don't understand how it got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand what exactly did happen which made the fix, but I can answer the other questions. BTW you can do a `git merge --abort` OR a `git reset --merge` as well to abort a merge if there are uncommitted changes.

> The two branches have the same SHA now. Is it certain now that master has everything? Should I check something else to make sure?

No, nothing else is required. The same SHA is enough.

If you could tell just a bit more about what happened (though you have given quite some detail but still) exactly *i.e.*, the state of `master` and `origin/master` before the merge etc., then I might be able to provide some answers to you :)

**E:** Looking at the exact use case of yours, the thing is that when you did a `git merge test-branch`, you *did* merge the `test-branch` into `master` yet everything happened locally while **you** were observing things on the remote. As soon as you did a `git push`, the changes were pushed to `origin/master` *i.e.*, the remote and hence *then* you observed the changes happen.

**E2:** One important concept about merging in Git is a "merge conflict". A merge conflict will occur when a file has two different changes at the same place from two different sources at once (such as two different changes in the `master` and `test-branch`). Now, let's say your merge would has a conflict, you may see something like:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in <fileName>
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

What this means is that Git saw two different changes and is depending upon you to fix it manually. Now, as I said, if you are unsure about things during the merge you can do `git merge --abort` OR a `git reset --merge` OR a `git reset --hard HEAD`. All of the three operations will give the same result *i.e.*, take you to the most recent commit you made. To add on, a `git reset --hard HEAD` will clean the staging area as well, meaning that if you had any other uncommitted changes apart from the merge too, they will get undone as well *i.e.*, get deleted and you will finally return to the most recent commit in your current working tree. Whereas `git merge --abort` OR a `git reset --merge` will just undo the ongoing merge by removing all the merge conflicts as well as any other changes which got merged.

Now that we have a good idea of merging and things related to it, let's proceed to your question: ***"Why didn't `git reset --hard HEAD` do anything?"***

The thing is that you never had any merge conflict in the first place (which is supported by the fact that you did not receive any error messages like the one I mentioned above). Therefore, there was nothing for `git reset` to wipe away as the latest commit **was** the merge commit and the staging area was clean, therefore `git reset` returned you to that merge commit itself hence you were not able to observe any changes because there weren't any in fact. I hope this satisfies your curiosity ;)

Best

Comment: Local and remote master were in sync, same stands for test. However, after the merge, I was looking only at the remote master. I didn't check what happened locally. After git merge test, should I do git push? I'm thinking maybe that is what happened.

Comment: Oh okay I got you, you were looking at the `origin/master` only hence you did not see the changes after the merge *until* you pushed. And hence that is why your problem got solved just after a`git push`! If you would’ve seen on the local repo, you would’ve been able to observe the changes there as well! I will edit my answer to accommodate this

Comment: Ok, I guess that was it, but I also did a `git reset --hard HEAD` before the `git push`. Why didn't this undo the merge?

Comment: Ahh I understand what you are asking, I will provide this in the answer too!

Comment: Made the requierd edits!
If this solves the problem, do mark this as solved :)